# PHP artisan controller error

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make a controller with PHP artisan but when I run command `php artisan make:controller TasksController` I confront with following error:

```
In RouteAction.php line 84:   
Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\TaskController].
```

why this error to be occur?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Plz show the full error

Comment: It happens when you try to load a route o when you digit `php artisan...` ecc ?

Comment: You seem to already have a file called TaskController, and you are trying to create TasksController, correct? And you have probably defined a route pointing to your TaskController, and most likely, to a method not existing in the TaskController, maybe a misspelled one?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi This is full error I get from console.

Comment: @OleHaugset No! I have not a file called TaskController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to execute `TaskController` without action. You need to add action to the controller:

```
Route::get('task', 'TaskController@someAction');
```

If you don't have a similar route, it means routes are cached with some wrong route. Since Artisan commands do not work, clear this cache manually by deleting this file:

```
bootstrap/cache/routes.php
```